# How do I run this command in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This is my batch script so far, but the files do not copy as desired. What is wrong with the script? The command "for /l %f... runs in cmdprompt, but not from a batch file.

```
echo off
echo Will it run?
pause
start for /l %f in (1,1,10) do copy "C:\Users\1\Desktop\medicine\m2_pics\fa2\Fa003b.jpg" "C:\Users\1\Desktop\medicine\m2_pics\fa2\Fa003b%f.jpg"
pause
exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `%f` with `%%f`. That's it. Variables which you access with `%varname` in the cmd console always turn to `%%varname` within a bat.